# Trying to get AJAX POST JSON on same index page

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to pass AJAX JSON POST value to the same page without refreshing each time one of the buttons is clicked. After the button is clicked I want to execute particular class or method ie; Add, Update or Delete.

I have achieved getting the POST value on same page but with HTML string. I have tired adding all the resources online to solve the problem but no luck (IE; JSON.stringify, json_decode, JSON.Parse etc.)

```php
echo $_POST['type'];
if (isset($_POST['type'])) 
{
    echo json_decode($_POST['type']);
}
```

```html
<a id="btnAdd" class="btnType" href="#" role="button">ADD</a><br>
<a id="btnUpdate" class="btnType" href="#" role="button">UPDATE</a><br>
<a id="btnDelete" class="btnType" href="#" role="button">DELETE</a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btnType').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopImmediatePropagation();

    var pageType;
    if ($(this).attr('id') === 'btnAdd') {
      pageType = 'add';
    } else if ($(this).attr('id') === 'btnUpdate') {
      pageType = 'update';
    } else if ($(this).attr('id') === 'btnDelete') {
      pageType = 'delete';
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        type: pageType
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#msg').html('<p>status code: ' + jqXHR.status +
          '</p><p>errorThrown: ' + errorThrown +
          '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p><div>' + jqXHR.responseText +
          '</div>');
        console.log('jqXHR:');
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log('textStatus:');
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log('errorThrown:');
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

[See the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaUEe.jpg)

Comment: just put exit statement after statement "echo json_decode($_POST['type']);" it will start working.

Comment: Also remove `echo $_POST['type'];`. The point is that the response needs to contain ***only*** JSON

Comment: @PrasadWargad I added the  exit statement as suggested. Now I get the following error 
"SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I get the following error

[Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:1:142)]

[See Error](https://ibb.co/gD4Y3fm)

Comment: Ok! I changed 

`echo json_decode($_POST['type']);` to 

`echo json_encode($_POST['type']);` 

It works !! now but only in console manager. How do I print on screen or get the POST ID value? The time I echo POST ID it gives me error
`errorThrown: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`